# Open colorbox on a non-link / href?

Tags: jquery, plugins, colorbox

I can't seem to find the right combination of search terms to get a nice example of using jquery colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/) on a non link / href for loading inline content.

I'd like to apply a class to a list item

since it will all be clickable and open the corresponding inline content div.

I'm just struggling with how to "feed" $.colorbox the ID that normally comes from the href="" attribute.

Thanks for any links / tips, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this since I see we can feed it a string of HTML to load.

```
$('.some-li').on('click', function(){
  $.colorbox({
    html: $('#div-to-load').html()
  });
});
```